# Проблема с кодировкой Chrome HTML+CSS

Tags: css, html5

Учусь вёрстке, пытаюсь создать резюме.
Столкнулся с проблемой кодировки: во всех остальных браузерах (Яндекс, Mi, Tor) всё работает нормально, а Chrome шифруется кракозябрами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно код увидеть?

Comment: Изменил, смотрите

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: Автокомпилятор неправильно отображает код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас после тега `<head>` не стоит кодировка. Вот так должно быть:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Кроме того, у Вас первая строка начинается с тега `<html>`, а должна начинаться с `<!DOCTYPE html>` и только второй строкой идет `<html>`
И `<link>` идет после `<title>`, а не перед

Comment: Спасибо, исправлю